# Unable to switch Django's databases settings using environment variables

Tags: django

I am trying to switch the database settings of my **Django** application using environment variables. So I made few changes in my `settings.py` file like this -

```
print(os.environ.get('DATABASE'))

if os.environ.get('DATABASE') == "DEVELOPMENT":
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        }
    }
else:
    print("i m here")
    DATABASES = { 
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
            'NAME': os.environ.get('DATABASE_NAME'),
            'USER': os.environ.get('DATABASE_USERNAME'),
            'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
            'HOST': os.environ.get('DATABASE_HOST'),
            'PORT': os.environ.get('DATABASE_PORT'),
            },
    }
```

Then I activated Python3 VirtualEnviroment and executed `export DATABASE=DEVELOPMENT` as shown in picture below -

[image]

When I start my application I get this from the `print()` -

```
None
i m here
None
i m here
```

It has also raised and exception -

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/jeetpatel/Desktop/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jeetpatel/Desktop/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Users/jeetpatel/Desktop/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 395, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/Users/jeetpatel/Desktop/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 382, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/jeetpatel/Desktop/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/Users/jeetpatel/Desktop/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/model_checks.py", line 34, in check_all_models
    errors.extend(model.check(**kwargs))
  File "/Users/jeetpatel/Desktop/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1274, in check
    *cls._check_constraints(),
  File "/Users/jeetpatel/Desktop/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1840, in _check_constraints
    connection.features.supports_table_check_constraints or
  File "/Users/jeetpatel/Desktop/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/jeetpatel/Desktop/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/features.py", line 93, in supports_column_check_constraints
    if self.connection.mysql_is_mariadb:
  File "/Users/jeetpatel/Desktop/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/jeetpatel/Desktop/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 363, in mysql_is_mariadb
    return 'mariadb' in self.mysql_server_info.lower()
  File "/Users/jeetpatel/Desktop/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/jeetpatel/Desktop/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 350, in mysql_server_info
    with self.temporary_connection() as cursor:
  File "/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py", line 112, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/Users/jeetpatel/Desktop/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 604, in temporary_connection
    with self.cursor() as cursor:
  File "/Users/jeetpatel/Desktop/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 24, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jeetpatel/Desktop/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 260, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/Users/jeetpatel/Desktop/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 236, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/Users/jeetpatel/Desktop/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 24, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jeetpatel/Desktop/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 220, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/jeetpatel/Desktop/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 24, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jeetpatel/Desktop/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 196, in connect
    conn_params = self.get_connection_params()
  File "/Users/jeetpatel/Desktop/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 206, in get_connection_params
    if settings_dict['HOST'].startswith('/'):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

I would like to know why is my `if` statement not working. Why am I not able to get the values from my environment variables.

Comment: check settings.DEBUG true or false.

Comment: Do you start your application from the same shell? Maybe try to edit the activate script and add it there?

Comment: @ytsejam DEGUG is True

Comment: @eran when I echo $DATABASE it returns DEVELOPMENT

Comment: @JeetPatel but how do you start your application? From the same shell

Comment: @eran I wasn't starting my app from same shell. But I took your suggestion and now it worked.

Comment: Great. Environment variables live only in the scope of the current shell (or its sub shells)